# How can I get pivot table from datable with using Linq in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable like this:

```
name    |   color of name
----------------------
x       |   red
y       |   blue
z       |   yellow
x       |   yellow
y       |   red
```

I need to get the pivot of this table like this:

```
name    |   red     |   blue    |   yellow  | total
-------------------------------------------------------
x       |   1       |   0       |   1       |   2
y       |   1       |   1       |   0       |   2
z       |   0       |   0       |   1       |   1
```

How can I do this with Linq in VB.NET?

The colors are not dynamic. i can put them in query in hardcoded.

So I need to group all records by name and sum of the records color in columns.
Then the sum of total colors(if you help in first one, i can calculate totals :p)

Comment: I would suggest considering it as two steps: 1. pivot the data 2. Add the `total` column. Are the `name` and `color of name` columns restricted to limited data sets or do you need a fully general solution?

Comment: It will help if you can edit the question and explain what you have tried already.

Comment: @NetMage you are totaly right. the big problem is first. Color names are restricted, they can be hardcoded. I need to group all the records by name, names are extremely large scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a variation of my `DataTable` pivot extension method that creates the intersection value based on the presence of the columns and adds a total column.

```
public static class DataTableExt {
    public static DataTable PivotByOverWithTotal(this DataTable dt, string ByRowFieldName, string OverColFieldName) {
        var res = new DataTable();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
            var dtg = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r[ByRowFieldName], r => r[OverColFieldName].ToString());

            res.Columns.Add(ByRowFieldName, dt.Columns[ByRowFieldName].DataType);
            var colNames = dtg.SelectMany(rg => rg).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);
            foreach (var n in colNames)
                res.Columns.Add(n, typeof(int));
            res.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(int));

            foreach (var rg in dtg) {
                var newr = res.NewRow();
                newr[ByRowFieldName] = rg.Key;
                int total = 0;
                foreach (var rv in colNames) {
                    var val = rg.Contains(rv) ? 1 : 0;
                    newr[rv] = val;
                    total += val;
                }
                newr["Total"] = total;
                res.Rows.Add(newr);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
var ansdt = src.PivotByOverWithTotal("name", "color");
```